# Connecting Domain to website without losing webmail

Tags: dns, cname, webmail

my domain is with Network Solutions. I also signed up for Email with them. So I should be able to use `http://mail.example.com` to access the webmail portal through my Browser.
If I change the nameservers to point to where my website is being hosted I lose the Webmail access.
If I keep the nameservers of my Domain Registrar, my website is not reachable.

Is there a way to use CNAME in the Advance settings to point to my website.
Everything I've read so far, it seems that this is more of an alias for a subdomain.

I would try the A Records if I knew the IP Addresses.

Answer (score 2):

If you change the nameservers then you need to update the `MX record` to tell the internet where to deliver mail.  An effective way to do this is to set your `MX Record` to `mail.example.com` and then create an `A Record` pointing to the IP address of Network Solutions mail server.  Their tech support should be able to tell you that.

Alternatively, if you leave the nameservers, you can update the `A Record` to tell the internet where your website is.  You should be able to get that from your web host.

If you *are* wanting to use webmail (See TomNewton's comment) you could try webmail.example.com - looking at DNS records should give you an idea

Comment: It is not so clear that OP asked about _Webmail access_, but not about email delivery.  Anyway, the overall approach is to use external service like https://dnschecker.org/  for validation of the `A and MX records`, IMHO

Comment: @TomNewton Oh, yeah, I missed that subtlety.  I will update my answer.